# AltGr on wireless keyboard connected to Dell 3350 laptop gives wrong result

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard-shortcuts

I have tried several wireless keyboards connected to my Dell 3350 laptop and ALtGR always opens a new explorer window! Extremly irritating everytime I try to print @, £ etc.
Can anyone help me solve this problem? I use win 7 Pro. Don´t have this problem when I use the keyboard on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your keyboard is in English, there are a few things worth noting:

1. You use the 'Shift' key (the ones on either side of your keyboard with the hollow up-arrow on them) to type out '£' or '@'
2. Your Windows keyboard region settings could be wrong, if you go to Control Panel -> Clock, Language & Region -> Language, you will see what language your keyboard is set to and change it there, it may change when you use a different keyboard.